# RapidWeaver-like editor for windows

Tags: user-interface, editor, gui-designer

After seeing a friend using RapidWeaver and producing wonderful results in a few clicks, I was astonished and started searching if a tool like that exists for Windows. Unfortunately, so far my search yielded no result, so I'm writing here the criteria I'm using hoping that anybody will come up with a relevant suggestion:

- WYSIWYG HTML editor
- Must work (well!) on Windows (Vista/7)
- Must not be web based (I don't care about webapps allowing me to create sites off of *crappy* templates)
- Template-based (and possibly with many templates available)
- Pretty flexible (nothing like Dreamweaver, but I wouldn't like being stuck with just entering text into some prebuilt templates)
- Intuitive (and possibly good looking) UI
- Producing standards-compliant markup (office-like HTML is not an option)

Here is what I **don't** care about:

- Price/License (if it's commercial it's probably even better for my purpose, as if the tool is good I will want fast, quality support)
- Good code editing features (when I'll get my hands dirty with the markup I want things to be looking already pretty good so I'll just have to improve certain areas based on my requirements...)
- Server-side scripting (I'm handling that otherwise, for this tool I just care about the design part)

Here's a list of commonly recommended tools I consider **unfit** for my needs:

- NVU
- KompoZer
- Microsoft Expression Web
- Microsoft Visual Web Designer
- Adobe Dreamweaver (good, but too good for my needs. At this stage, I'd prefer something quicker, even if it means having lower quality html)

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: Why do you consider the tools in your list to be "unfit"?

Comment: Was running exactly under the same problem. You saved my life ! Thanks a million !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably too late, and not sure if this helps you anyway:

http://www.artisteer.com

http://www.xara.com/eu/products/webdesigner/

Comment: I've actually opted for aristeer a few months ago, however the effort will be rewarded :)